# android - getting all rows from external database - good idea?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, django

I have an application in android, a database on the server and I wrote api in django. I want for my application to work online and offline. So far I did local database in android and api returns query results in json. (database is very simply, just one table with 7 fields). But I don't know nothing about databases performance. I wonder if a good strategy is to getting all rows from table (from server), delete all rows from local database, and save all new rows to local database? Or update all fields in existing rows? Or maybe online/offline app is not a good idea? How long can take downloading 1000 rows from database on server?
Maybe this is silly question, but really, I'm looking for a solution ;)

my model in Django looks like that:

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    quote = models.TextField(verbose_name="Quotation")
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Accepted")
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Deleted")
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date", auto_now=True)
    good = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Rate good")
    bad = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Rate bad")

class Favourite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote)
```

And I send by json only table Quote (username, quote, accepted, deleted, date, good, bad).
An api function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        operation = request.POST['operation']
        print 'operation', operation
        response_data = {}
        response_data['result'] = 'FAILED'

        if operation == 'getFive':
            itemsList = []
            ID = int(request.POST['id'])

            if ID == -1:
                querySet = Quote.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('-id')[:5]
            else:
                querySet = Quote.objects.filter(id__lt=ID, deleted=False).order_by('-id')[:5]

            maxID = Quote.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('-id')[0].id
            minID = Quote.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('id')[0].id

            for item in querySet:
                tmp = {}
                tmp['id'] = item.id
                tmp['username'] = item.user.username
                tmp['quote'] = item.quote
                tmp['accepted'] = item.accepted
                tmp['deleted'] = item.deleted
                tmp['date'] = dateformat.format(item.date, "Y-m-d H:i:s")
                tmp['good'] = item.good
                tmp['bad'] = item.bad
                itemsList.append(tmp)
                print item.id, item.quote
            response_data['result'] = 'SUCCESS'
            response_data['items'] = itemsList
            response_data['maxID'] = maxID
            response_data['minID'] = minID

            response_data['items'] = itemsList
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
    return redirect("/")
```

My problem is that I don't want to user wait very long time to run the application and I don't how long data can be downloaded by smartphone with HSDPA/3G/LTE etc. where are ~1000 rows in table. Let's say there is ~1500 characters by one row. If I counted good it's 1500 B * 1000 rows = 1500000 Bytes = 1464 KB = ~1,42 MB... So I think it's much, but I'm not an expert.

I forgot add, that when row have 'deleted'=True, I don't send it to smartphone.

And my question again: **Sending all rows from server to android app, every time when app starts, is a good idea?**

Thanks, and sorry for my english ;).

Comment: The simplest solution that works is the best. It will be hard to answer this unless you show something real (code, profiling results).

Answer (score 0):

I can explain a solution for ya, but I cannot really show you how to do it.

1. You only want to get all rows if its the first time the user is opening your app. So youll do an update if not exist to your local DB.
2. When you are doing this, you will want it to be in the background so the user can go ahead and start poking around your application. Maybe do a toast to display that the background thread is downloading the records and it might take a while.
3. Break up the download with a cursor to only download x records at a time. Download 50 and return, download 50 and return. That way the user can see the records being downloaded and they do not have to wait until ALL records are returned.